# AVG function postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query

```
SELECT humidity_float 
FROM   labs_climate_measuring_room 
       INNER JOIN labs_climate_measuring 
               ON labs_climate_measuring.id = 
                  labs_climate_measuring_room.measuring_id 
       INNER JOIN labs_room 
               ON labs_room.id = labs_climate_measuring_room.room_id 
WHERE  labs_climate_measuring_room.room_id = 81 
       AND labs_climate_measuring.action_time <= '2019-12-18 06:00:00' 
       AND labs_room.is_conditioning_room = true 
       AND humidity_float IS NOT NULL 
ORDER  BY labs_climate_measuring.action_time
```

which return two rows. I need to get an average value of it. So I do this

```
SELECT avg(humidity_float) OVER (PARTITION BY temperature_float) AS cum_amt
```

This also returns two rows. How get average value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need PARTITION, just aggregate:

```
SELECT AVG(humidity_float) AS cum_amt
FROM labs_climate_measuring_room 
INNER JOIN labs_climate_measuring ON labs_climate_measuring.id = labs_climate_measuring_room.measuring_id
INNER JOIN labs_room ON labs_room.id = labs_climate_measuring_room.room_id 
WHERE labs_climate_measuring_room.room_id = 81
and labs_climate_measuring.action_time <= '2019-12-18 06:00:00'
AND labs_room.is_conditioning_room = TRUE
AND humidity_float IS NOT NULL
```

and also you don't need ORDER BY.